# Stop current pytest execution but continue to run other cases

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, sys

I am running tests using `pytest` on python.

In the tested code, some conditions trigger a `sys.exit(non_zero_code)`, using `pytest`, we want to make sure that `sys.exit` is called under those conditions, but obviously we do not want the system to really exit, so we mock `sys`.

The problem is that now, the rest of the code will continue to execute, which I do not want. If I call `pytest.exit`, the whole process exit, when I just really want only that test case to stop at this point.

A good way to visualize is to read this simple example, the *"Should not execute, we exited"* line will be hit when we run the tests

```
import os
import sys

import pytest
import logging
from pathlib import Path

logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), "pytest_log"),
                    filemode='a',
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def function_with_exit(value):

    if value == 2:
        sys.exit(2)
        logger.info("Should not execute, we exited")

    logger.info("Value is not 2")


def side_effect():
    logger.info("Sys exit was called")


@pytest.mark.parametrize("value", [1, 2, 3])
def test_with_pytest(mocker, value):
    mocker.patch(__name__ + '.' + sys.__name__)

    function_with_exit(value)
```

I need to modify the mock to:

- Not hit the line when the second test case is run
- Continue running the next test case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From python docs

> Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit
> the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not
> intercepted. Cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try
> statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit
> attempt at an outer level.

A call to `sys.exit()` will only create and raise a new `SystemExit` exception and raise it, This is not inherited from the usual `Exception` class but from the `BaseException` class, So it does not get caught with any regular exception handlers, instead they get escalated to the interpreter and interpreter cleans things neatly and exists.

You can catch this in pytest and perform the needed asserts.

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as exc:
    function_with_exit()
    assert exc.value.code == 2
```

Comment: Indeed, using pytest.raises seems in this case the best way to go !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mocking `sys.exit()`, you should just handle the `SystemExit` exception it raises:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("value", [1, 2, 3])
def test_with_pytest(value):
    try:
        function_with_exit(value)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```